# React native IOS app archives but won't show in Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have tried turning skip install (on) for project and static frameworks, and off for main target, and still get the same issue. It archives, but won't show in Organizer, and when I go to open the archive file it says it is corrupted. Please help.